# Are the crocodiles Steve Irwin rescued in Dili, East Timor in 2000 still there?

Tags: sightseeing

In 2000, Steve "Crocodile Hunter" Irwin and his crew [rescued two crocodiles in Dili, East Timor](https://ntnews.com.au/news/northern-territory/saltwater-crocs-on-timorese-military-based-were-saved-by-aussie-soldiers-and-steve-irwin/news-story/4c71b594155531c52abf4f761e399d49) and took them to a new custom-built enclosure at "the Metinaro Military Base, about 30km from Dili".

**Are the crocodiles still there, and is the site accessible to the public?**

For context, saltwater crocodiles can live for over 70 years, so it's entirely possible they're still alive -- but Google finds no military bases or anything crocodile-related [near Metinaro](https://maps.app.goo.gl/mofkFCBST349TQ64A), although apparently there are wild crocodiles in the mangroves nearby.

Comment: According to [this](https://nautilus.org/publications/books/australian-forces-abroad/australian-bases-abroad/metinaro-training-base/) site, part of the Metinaro base is at [8.5169S 125.7819E](https://www.google.com/maps/place/8°31'00.8%22S+125°46'54.8%22E/@-8.5169,125.7819,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m4!3m3!8m2!3d-8.5169!4d125.7819).  It wouldn't surprise me that Indonesia has requested google to purge military base data. Especially in East Timor, given the history of the area.  It's also possible that this is no longer a military base (based on the comment about a mutiny at the base in 2006)

Comment: @PeterM Interesting find!   The satellite imagery is reasonable quality, it looks like this spot might be the (former?) crocodile enclosure: https://goo.gl/maps/gZonapmzB3SjK85g8  I don't think Indonesia has anything to do with this, East Timor was independent by 2000 and Google Earth Engine Timelapse indicates the base didn't even exist until 2000.